# How to change the order of elements in a matched jQuery set

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filter, set

I am writing a javascript based filter:

There a lots of divs with the class `.single` that contain multiple text elements. The filter already hides all `.single`'s that do not contain words:

```
//take them off dom, manip and put them back
singles.detach().each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);

    //make sure everything is visible
    $this.show();

    //if this template is not included OR if this index number does not meet the treshold
    if($.inArray(i, included) == -1 || treshold >= templates[i].score) {
        $this.hide();
    }
}).appendTo(container);
```

The array `included` contains all indexes of `.single`'s that contain atleast one word. The array `templates` contains objects with all the text per `.single` and a score based on relevance and number of words. For example:

```
templates = [
    { text: ['long string', 'long string 2'], score: 5 },
    { text: ['sf sd', 'gdasd'], score: 3 }
]
```

(So all indexing doesn't happen in the DOM)

Now what I want is to sort the set based on this score, or in other words: the highest score on the top. The index of each element in the set is the same as the index in `templates` (which contains all scores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the score to elements as  data() in your $.each

```
$(this).data('score', templates[i].score);
```

You could then use the scores to sort

```
function scoreSort(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('score') > $(b).data('score') ?1 :-1;

}

singles.sort( scoreSort);

/* now replace html*/

container.append( singles);
```

I may be missing something, you say you want them in index order of `templates` but they must already be in that order for you to look at scores in `templates` using index in $.each

Comment: I'm using $(elem).each() and not $.each(). templates and the set are already in the same order so I can bind the score using `data` (thanks for the tip). However the sort you suggested does not sort on score but instead shows different results (I don't get why).

Comment: you're right, it works. It must be my other code then. Thanks for the solution!